# Javascript wall physics and ground physics

Tags: javascript, game-physics

After the element or game-piece collides with the wall it stops moving. How can i reset the collision detection so that after the game-piece collides with the wall it is still able to move? Also after the game-piece collides with the ground it stops moving to. So how can i reset that collision detection so that it can move after colliding with the wall?

```
var myGamePiece;
var myObstacle;
var e = e || window.event;
var speed = 3;
var gravity = 0.05;
function startGame() {
 myGamePiece = new component(30, 30, "red", 10, 120);
 myObstacle = new component(10, 200, "green", 300, 120);
 myGameArea.start();
 myGameArea.gravityPhysics();
}

var myGameArea = {
 canvas: document.createElement("canvas"),
  start: function() {
   this.canvas.width = 480;
   this.canvas.height = 270;
   this.context = this.canvas.getContext("2d");
   document.body.insertBefore(this.canvas, document.body.childNodes[0]);
   this.interval = setInterval(updateGameArea, 20);
 },
 clear: function() {
  this.context.clearRect(0, 0, this.canvas.width, this.canvas.height);
 },
  gravityPhysics: function() {
   myGamePiece.speedY = -speed;
 },
 stop: function() {
   clearInterval(this.interval);
 }
};

 function component(width, height, color, x, y) {
  this.width = width;
  this.height = height;
  this.speedX = 0;
  this.speedY = 0;
  this.x = x;
  this.y = y;
  this.update = function() {
    ctx = myGameArea.context;
    ctx.fillStyle = color;
    ctx.fillRect(this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height);
    this.hitBottom();
  };
  this.crashWith = function(otherobj) {
    var myleft = this.x;
    var myright = this.x + this.width;
    var mytop = this.y;
    var mybottom = this.y + this.height;
    var otherleft = otherobj.x;
    var otherright = otherobj.x + otherobj.width;
    var othertop = otherobj.y;
    var otherbottom = otherobj.y + otherobj.height;
    var crash = true;

    if (
      mybottom < othertop ||
      mytop > otherbottom ||
      myright < otherleft ||
      myleft > otherright
    ) {
      crash = false;
    }

    return crash;
  };
  this.hitBottom = function() {
    var rockbottom = myGameArea.canvas.height - this.height;

    if (this.y > rockbottom) {
      this.y = rockbottom;

      if (
        myGameArea.canvas.height - this.height &&
        myGamePiece.key == 38
      ) {
        this.y = this.speedY;
      }

      this.gravitySpeed = 0; // reset?
    }
  };
}

function updateGameArea() {
  if (myGamePiece.crashWith(myObstacle)) {
    console.log("crash");
  } else {
    myGameArea.clear();
    myObstacle.update();
    myGamePiece.x += myGamePiece.speedX;
    myGamePiece.y -= myGamePiece.speedY;
    myGamePiece.update();
  }
   if (
    myGameArea.gravityPhysics() &&
    e.keyCode == document.addEventListener("keydown")
  ) {
   myGamePiece.speedY = gravity - 10;
    e.keyCode = true;
  }
}
document.onkeydown = checkKeyD;
document.onkeyup = gravityPhysics;

function checkKeyD(e) {
  if (e.keyCode == "38") {
    // up arrow
    myGamePiece.speedY = speed;
  } else if (e.keyCode == "40") {
    // down arrow
    myGamePiece.speedY = -speed;
  } else if (e.keyCode == "37") {
    // left arrow
    myGamePiece.speedX = -speed;
  } else if (e.keyCode == "39") {
    // right arrow
    myGamePiece.speedX = speed;
  }
}
if ((e = e || (window.event && window.event == false))) {
  myGamePiece.speedY -= gravity;
}
function clearmove() {
  myGamePiece.speedX = 0;
  myGamePiece.speedY = 0;
}
```